# Interactive Map for Shopping Malls

Tags: apache-flex, maps

I am trying to build a product that shows users interactive maps and helps them navigate through a shopping mall.

For that I am thinking of building a content management system(in Flex 4) so that map creation and shops identification process can be streamlined and non-technical users can use it.

Any ideas on where to start or which APIs to use?

Regards,
Raheel Imtiaz

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd build a core set of 'map components' all based on (or using) degrafa classes.  In fact, I just went to the site and found that someone already built a 'map builder' application here:  http://www.degrafa.org/samples/rich-user-interface.html  (the links for samples are under the 'sample categories' area on the right... that should get you started).

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I have tried opening the MapBuilder link but unfortunately the link is down. But anyways i'll give degrafa try as well. In the meantime, i would love to have new ideas as well.